# Connecting BLE module to Lipo battery and recharge it?

Tags: batteries, bluetooth-low-energy, module

I would like to use a BLE module, where I can solder a tactile switch. There should be also the option to charge the module via USB. Earlier I have only worked with breakout boards, where I could connect the battery to the GND and VCC pin. Now I would like to use the BLE module directly to reduce the size of the device.

I have worked with the [NRF51822](https://eckstein-shop.de/Waveshare-Bluetooth-40-BLE-24G-Wireless-Module-NRF51822-Core-Board-Small-Factor?curr=EUR&gclid=Cj0KCQjwj_XpBRCCARIsAItJiuTDHNoI36b2sruw3riCvaQkpYB5reBx4niJFw_YanP2xDhjBdlfrH0aAvCxEALw_wcB) before which should meet my requirements. Unfortunately I am really new to schematics and struggling with the information provided by it. I also wondered about the naming of the pins. Is there a convention and official list where I can find more information? Could you explain me how I can find out what the different notation stands for? Is there a general legend?
[image: Schematic of NRF51822]

The schematic of the board for the 51822 is listed [here](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/57/Core51822-Schematic.pdf). Do you have any good literature for the wording and understanding of these schemes? Can I simply connect the battery to VDD and DCC? Doing a Google search for "VDD" is not that helpful.

I would use it with a Lipo charger like [this](https://www.reichelt.de/entwicklerboards-ladegeraet-fuer-li-ion-lipo-akkus-mit-microu-debo-power2-p235492.html?PROVID=2788&gclid=Cj0KCQjwj_XpBRCCARIsAItJiuTrr_fPJY0cF-R52N9K45vOe_Q9FtoYyFUnJhQPZ2L_rWgQ5zqWyZkaAm6ZEALw_wcB&&r=1). Would you recommend such a charger or what is the most elegant way?

Comment: We would all have to follow three links just to understand what you are asking. Can you inline the relevant images or specifications and ask specific questions on parts you don't understand?

Comment: Sure, I will include the schematic. I do not understand what the names stand for (e.g. DCC, VDD, P0.30).

Comment: That's fine. Make that clear in your question.

Comment: You've linked to a catalog page for the device. You need to identify the chip on the board and get the datasheet for that.

Comment: This maintains all of the problems of your previous improper question on this project save one.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450358/cheapest-ble-device-with-gpio indicating that you still do not understand the rules for what types of questions may not be asked here

Comment: Do not connect this to a lipo battery, as explained at your previous question a coin cell is enough.  If you did any actual research you would find that could run it at a heavier usage than yours for years.

Comment: I am thinking about using the nRF nrf52840 instead. There it should be possible to connect a lipo, right? It seems to have a power supply up to 5.5V. So can I simply solder the battery to GND and VDDH? That is how I would understand the schematic. But I am not sure how I can connect the Lipo charger mentioned above. How do I have to connect this?